# Why i cant use the 3306 port when i install MySQL?

Tags: mysql, installation, port

I am trying to install mySQL but on the type and networking section said that the port of 3306 is already in use. What can i do? I already have the xampp on my pc! This port is used by xampp? i have to put it on an other port or what?

Expecting someone to help me!

Comment: Find out which process is using the port (I guess an other mysql/mariadb) stop the process and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change the port of either XAMPP or Mysql in the configuration.

You can simply rerun the installer of MySQL and change it in the setup config in "Type and Networking" - "Development Computer" - "TCP/IP" - Enter another port which is not used

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. how do i know which port is not used?

Comment: I guess you are using windows. Here you can see a list of used ports: https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/security/checking-open-ports/

My suggestion would be just a +1 and try if it is free for exmaple 3307

Answer (score 0):

if you already have installed Xampp you change the port from the config after opening the Xampp, Then Mysql will select the port that is available. if error still persist then check which ports are available using:

netstat -an | find "your_port"